# Can Non-Us developer make sandbox account in Paypal?

Tags: android, paypal, payment-gateway

I wanted to Integrate Payment gateway in my application.I chose Pay-pal for that.I am non-us developer. i couldn't make account in https://developer.paypal.com. Can Anyone have solution or link for making Account in Paypal(for Non-us Developer)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, The new Mobile SDKs are available in multiple countries where REST APIs are available as mentioned in the FAQs. Please see below the list of countries and country specific policies/process.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

Suppose your country not listed there then also you can use in your country.. just convert your currency to supported currency by using google finance Api...

Comment: alternativaly you can consume paypal soap Api.

Answer (score 1):

Source: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#international-developer-questions

**What countries does PayPal support?**

The REST API supports a number of countries and currencies. To check REST API support for direct credit card payments for a US account, see the Account eligibility page. Direct credit card support in the REST API is available in the UK if you sign up for a UK Website Payments Pro account.

For countries not yet supported by the REST API, you can use the NVP/SOAP APIs to accept credit cards and PayPal purchases from over 190 countries that PayPal supports. Alternatively, integrate with the SDKs that use the NVP/SOAP APIs.

**I'm a non-U.S. developer. What products are available to me?**

The REST API supports a number of countries and currencies. The REST API provides simple payment processing for common business needs, including PayPal payments, direct credit card payments, authorization and capture, and refunds. For more advanced payment solutions such as parallel and recurring payments, you can use the NVP/SOAP APIs.

If you've previously used our NVP/SOAP APIs, you can continue to use them. Using your old Sandbox email address and password, you can import existing Sandbox accounts on the Sandbox Accounts page.